# Отобразить title родительской категории товаров в дочерней категории

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress. У меня получилось вывести `url` родительской категории внутри дочерней категории при помощи такого кода:

```
$cat = get_queried_object();
$parent_cat_id = $cat->parent;

echo get_category_link( $parent_cat_id )
```

Подскажите, как вывести `title` родительской категории?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вам нужно использовать функции для работы с таксономией

```
$term = get_term( $parent_cat_id, 'product_cat' );

echo get_term_link( $term );
echo $term->name;
```